# GNU grep with `-file-name` gives error `ile-name: No such file or directory`

Tags: grep

When I tried to find pattern '-file-name', I got strange error messages

```
jaewan@lymose1:~$ grep -file-name README.txt 
grep: ile-name: No such file or directory
jaewan@lymose1:~$ grep \-file-name README.txt 
grep: ile-name: No such file or directory
jaewan@lymose1:~$ grep '-file-name' README.txt 
grep: ile-name: No such file or directory
jaewan@lymose1:~$ grep '\-file-name' README.txt 
-- works well
```

I think that grep interpret '-file-name' as an -f ile-name if I don't use '-file-name'.
I read documents about grep and regular expression, but I could not found the reason.
At a glance, in my opinion, also -file-name should work.

Is this a GNU grep bug? or common linux style?

GNU grep version is 2.5.4

Answer (score 4):

That's standard POSIX argument processing.  Two ways around it:

```
grep -e -file-name README.txt
grep -- -file-name README.txt
```

The first marks the next argument as being the regular expression even if it looks like an option; the second turns off option parsing, so anything following `--` is taken as an argument and not an option.

Answer (score 2):

Use `-e` before the pattern to prevent it from being interpreted as an option.

```
   -e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
          Use PATTERN as the pattern; useful to protect patterns beginning
          with -.
```

So, your code should read:

```
grep -e -file-name README.txt
```

Your tries in escaping only reached the shell, not `grep` which is why you didn't see any changed behavior.